# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int' , trying to print a simple message

Tags: python-3.x

This is my first day learning Python and I can't get a message to appear like I want.

This is just for some practice. I've already tried moving the quotations around but that didn't do anything.

```
favorite_number = 28
print("My favorite number is ") + favorite_number
```

I just want the output to be able to say `My favorite number is 28`

Answer (score 1):

You put the concatenation *outside* the call to `print`, so you're taking the return value from `print` (which has no meaningful return, and therefore returns `None`) and trying to add it to your `int` value.

To fix, pass your value as a separate `print` argument:

```
print("My favorite number is", favorite_number)
```

or perform the concatenation inside the `print` parentheses (which also requires converting to `str` explicitly, as `str + int` is not legal):

```
print("My favorite number is " + str(favorite_number))
```

or use formatting, either the `.format` method or f-strings to create the combined string:

```
# format method
print("My favorite number is {}".format(favorite_number))
# f-strings
print(f"My favorite number is {favorite_number}")
```

All of those but the first involve creating an extra temporary string that hold your entire output message, so for the `print` case, I'd recommend the first option, but when you're not immediately printing, f-strings are probably the way to go, assuming you know you'll run on modern (3.6+) Python.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you put the closing parenthesis in the wrong place. What if you try this instead?

```
print("My favorite number is " + favorite_number)
```

Well, this will also throw an error: `TypeError: must be str, not int`. That tells us we need to convert the `int` to `str` first:

```
print("My favorite number is " + str(favorite_number))
```

This works! But there's a better way to do it. `print` will automatically convert each of its arguments to `str` and join them with spaces, so we just need to give `favorite_number` as a separate argument:

```
print("My favorite number is", favorite_number)
```

But why did you get that specific error in the first place? (`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'`) It's because `print` doesn't have anything useful to return, so it returns `None`, and `None` doesn't support addition/concatenation.